# How to Get Kibana Visualization SVG in Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, svg, kibana, visualization

is it possible to get a Kibana Visualization in SVG format in Python by using the Visualization ID. I would like to use the SVG in and HTML page programmatically to send an HTML mail

Answer (score 0):

You can get a embed link to dashboard/visualization from kibana and then use it as a iframe src in your html.

[image]

Comment: But how can I get this embed link through a code (Python)? Is there any API or library which accepts visualization ID and gives back svg?

Comment: Do you really need to get this link dynamically. Your  dashboards will remain constant. isnt it ?

Comment: The date range for the visualization would change as well

Comment: Ah yes you are right. I could manage to get the iframe and change dates dynamically. But is there a way I can get SVG of the visualization as I want to send the visualization in an Email and I cannot use iframe

Comment: @SomeshGarje pls accept the answer if it solves your queries..

Comment: you can send html with iframe

Comment: But iframe cannot be sent over email as it is not supported element in exchange